# PHP what is the difference between { } and {{ }}

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm using PHP Laravel framework and I came to some code examples where {{ }} is use inside a html code, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href=" {{ URL::to('css/app.css') }} ">
```

My conclusion is that the {{ }} are used to write no-HTML code inside the HTML, is that correct?

And for what is the { } used?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Specifically a Blade templating/Laravel question rather than PHP.... they're placeholders for displayed values in the Blade templating system, one for unescaped values, the other for escaped values (though that's Laravel 4, not 5)

Comment: If you want to learn PHP, you shouldn't use a framework. You don't realize the difference between plain PHP and what a framework like Laravel does behind the scene. `{{ }}` is used in Laravel's Template Engine Blade. The docs are on http://laravel.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `{ }` in Blade, `{{ }}` displays escaped data and `{!! !!}` displays unescaped data.

> By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through
>   PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want
>   your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:
>
> ```
> Hello, {!! $name !!}.
> ```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#displaying-data

Answer (score 1):

That is not php but rather syntax for the [blade template system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade) that laravel comes bundeled with.

In short, `{{$aPhpVariable}}` is basically compiled to `<?= htmlentities($aPhpVariable) ?>` (or even `<?php echo htmlentities($aPhpVariable); ?>`), but from what I know, there is no single bracket (`{}`) syntax.

You can also use normal php code inside blade templates or just treat it as a normal html page, but it does have a bunch of things that makes building the views a lot easier.
Go check out the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade) for more info about blade!

Answer (score 0):

To escape data use

```
{{ $data }}
```

If you don't want the data to be escaped use :

```
{!! $data !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `{}` is part of the syntax of PHP code. It's used in functions, blocks of code and objects.
2. `{{ }}` it part of Laravel's Blade template syntax, echoing something in a  Laravel project.